# Get substring with only available chars from index

Tags: java, string, substring

Is there any string function in Java that will allow me to extract the substring like  QString::mid:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid

When index exceeds string length, I want the function to return empty string, and when index+length of substring is greater, I want the function to return only available characters.

I have written piece of code that does it, but I refuse to believe such fuction is not in Java already:

```
private static String  Mid(String s, int index, int length){
    if(s.length()>=length+index){
        return s.substring(index, length+index);
    }
    else if(s.length()>=index) {
        return s.substring(index, s.length());
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Is there something like this in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just need `Math.min` a couple of times:

```
int start = Math.min(index, s.length());
int end = Math.min(index + length, s.length());
return s.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: While I like this approach it will allow `start` and `end` to end up out of String negative bounds. But since OP also didn't handle this case it is still nicer than original approach. `index = Math.max(index, 0); length = Math.max(length, 0);` could handle this, but maybe you will figure out something cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there is no mid function on the String class in Java itself.

However, the Apache Commons StringUtils library has the [mid](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#mid(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) method and other String manipulation functions. It is useful to get familiar with all the Apache commons libraries as they are widely used, open-sourced and save having to reinvent the wheel.